# How to test a form submission and verify an email is sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a button that opens a modal window containing a simple form to send an email. The only field is the message, and my controller populates hidden email to and email from fields. The form only sends a message, so there is no model.

How would I write a test to verify an email is sent?

My route

```
match '/contact_guide', to: 'contact#contact_guide', via: 'post'
```

Controller

```
def contact_guide
# Send mail to a guide. 

email_from = params[:email_from]
email_to = params[:email_to]
body = params[:message]
name = params[:name]

ContactMailer.contact_guide(name, email_to, email_from, body).deliver_now
flash[:success] = 'Message sent'

# Go back to the guide page.
u = User.find_by(email: email_to)
g = u.guide
redirect_to guide_url(g)
end
```

The form HTML

```
    <%= form_tag(contact_guide_path) do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'message', 'Contact Guide' %>
    <%= text_area_tag 'message', nil, class: 'form-control', 
        rows: 4, placeholder: 'Message...', :required => true %>

    <!-- Hidden to email field -->
    <%= label_tag 'email_to', 'Email', style: 'visibility:hidden;display:none' %>
    <%= email_field_tag 'email_to', nil, class: 'form-control', 
        style: 'visibility:hidden;display:none', value: @guide.user.email %>

    <!-- Hidden from email field -->
    <%= label_tag 'email_from', 'Email', style: 'visibility:hidden;display:none' %>
    <%= email_field_tag 'email_from', nil, class: 'form-control', 
        style: 'visibility:hidden;display:none', value: @email_from %>

    <!-- Hidden guide name field -->
    <%= label_tag 'name', 'Name', style: 'visibility:hidden;display:none' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, class: 'form-control', 
        style: 'visibility:hidden;display:none', value: @guide.user.name %>

    <%= submit_tag "Send Message", class: 'btn btn-default btn-about contact-btn' %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

In my test I'm trying to do this

```
 post contact_guide_path, {message: "This is a message."}
```

But I get the error

```
ArgumentError Exception: An SMTP From address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_from, return_path, sender, or from address.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add few missing parameters in post statement.

```
post contact_guide_path, {message: "This is a message."}
```

make it to:

```
post contact_guide_path, {message: "This is a message.",email_to: "[testing email]", email_from: "[Testint email]" , name: 'ABC'}
```

Comment: I'm working on cloud9, not local host. I think the problem is with my post statement. I don't understand it, and I can't find any documentation on how to use it.

Comment: in post statement try this `{message: "This is a message.",email_to: "[testing email]", email_from: "[Testint email]" , name: 'ABC'}`

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with the syntax. Using email_to, email_from, and name in my post works, and I can verify an email was sent.